# How to style a mat-select selected option?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I want to change the color of the selected option text of a mat-select on Angular 15.

.html

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>From</mat-label>
     <mat-select panelClass="mat-select-red">
         <mat-option>January</mat-option>
         <mat-option>February</mat-option>
         <mat-option>March</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts

ViewEncapsulation is set to none.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

.scss

I have tried all of these and none worked.

```
.mat-select-red.mat-mdc-select-value-text{
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-select-red.mat-select-value-text{
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-select-red.mat-mdc-select-value{
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-select-red.mat-select-value{
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-select-red.mat-mdc-select{
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-select-red.mat-select{
  color: red !important;
}

.mat-select-red.mat-mdc-select-min-line{
  color: red !important;
}

mat-mdc-form-field{
  color: red;
}
```

Note: The following css works and is correctly applied. But it changes the background color. I want to change the text color of the selected value.

```
.mat-select-red.mat-mdc-select-panel {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

UPDATE

Adding the rendered html per request.

```
<mat-select role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="listbox" formcontrolname="startMonth" panelclass="mat-select-red" class="mat-mdc-select ng-tns-c33-1 ng-tns-c20-0 ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched ng-dirty" ng-reflect-panel-class="mat-select-red" ng-reflect-name="startMonth" aria-labelledby="mat-mdc-form-field-label-0 mat-select-value-1" id="mat-select-0" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false"><div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-mdc-select-trigger ng-tns-c33-1"><div class="mat-mdc-select-value ng-tns-c33-1" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false" id="mat-select-value-1"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><span class="mat-mdc-select-value-text ng-tns-c33-1 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false"><span class="mat-mdc-select-min-line ng-tns-c33-1 ng-star-inserted">February</span><!--container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--></span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--></div><div class="mat-mdc-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c33-1"><div class="mat-mdc-select-arrow ng-tns-c33-1"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" focusable="false" class="ng-tns-c33-1"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z" class="ng-tns-c33-1"></path></svg></div></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-open": "false"
}--></mat-select>
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @Jon P I updated the question adding the html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the color of the selected option using this, hope it helps

```css
/* TEXT COLOR WHEN OPTION IS SELECTED*/
.mat-mdc-option.mdc-list-item--selected:not(.mdc-list-item--disabled) .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
  color: red !important;
}
```